# Swift 4 Sqlite database no such table error

Tags: swift, sqlite, fmdb

I'm working at the very limit of my newbie understanding here and I'm struggling to understand what I'm doing wrong.  So, I've created a database in DB Browser for SQLite, I've saved as a .db file and I've also exported to a .sql file.  It is a single table with a numeric key and the name of a city.  It's the basis of a bigger database I have planned. I've added all the FMDB stuff as per the GitHub page instructions.  I've added the database to my project (dragged it from Finder into the left hand pane of Xcode). I've tried both individually and together the .db and .sql files and ensured they were added to target.  I've then added the following code to `viewDidLoad()' in the`ViewController` where I want to create an array from the database contents.

```
// test db code

    let fileURL = try! FileManager.default
        .url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        .appendingPathComponent("Wanderer.db")

    let database = FMDatabase(url: fileURL)

    guard database.open() else {
        print("Unable to open database")
        return
    }

    do {

        let cities:FMResultSet = try database.executeQuery("SELECT City from Cities", values: nil)

        while cities.next() {

            if let result = cities.string(forColumn: "City") {

            cityData.append(result)

            }

        }


    } catch {

        print("OOPS, some sort of failure")
    }


    //end test db code
```

When I run my app on the Simulator and the relevant page loads, I get the following error in my debug console:

> 2018-10-29 20:00:43.194628+0000 Wanderer[9708:849273] DB Error: 1 "no
>   such table: Cities"
>
> 2018-10-29 20:00:43.194808+0000 Wanderer[9708:849273] DB Query: SELECT
>   City from Cities
>
> 2018-10-29 20:00:43.194917+0000 Wanderer[9708:849273] DB Path:
>   /Users/robmunro2/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/98971BF4-8901-4E3D-8D71-1CF3E4117885/data/Containers/Data/Application/7421C242-AA18-409E-BC61-ABB5FA5D2A98/Library/Application
>   Support/Wanderer.db OOPS, some sort of failure

What on earth am I doing wrong!?

Comment: Do you really sure that this file exists at `/Users/robmunro2/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/98971BF4-8901-4E3D-8D71-1CF3E4117885/data/Containers/Data/Application/7421C242-AA18-409E-BC61-ABB5FA5D2A98/Library/Application Support/`?

Comment: Good question.  Just selected the path and went to Finder -> Go and the path only takes me to the Application folder.  There doesn't seem to be a 7421C242-AA18-409E-BC61-ABB5FA5D2A98/Library/Application Support/ set of subfolders.  Ummm?

Comment: yes. Just debug it .

Comment: Make sure the file is associated to the target in the inspector.

Comment: Sorry, newbie question but how do I do that?  When I added the file to the project (dragged into the same place as the .swift files etc) I made sure the target was ticked.

Comment: Hi, just played around with a few things and found the file where the error log said it should be but noticed the .db file was shown as zero bytes suggesting it is empty.  It is a very small table but I'd still expect it to be a few bytes in size.  Does that point to a particular issue?

Comment: Is the zero bytes file the one you copied into project? Or the from the simulator?

Comment: I think you are not copying your Sqlite db from project to documents directory properly. if in your project sqlite db contains the table then please delete your application as on every new launch it will create a new document directory and will copy a new database.

Comment: I'm assuming it is the simulator given the obscure file path.

Comment: I must admit to being a bit confused about all these directories.  Is the document directory just my standard one in Finder or is it unique to Xcode?  I'm assuming my project directory is where all the files are for my project in my case under a subfolder /Software Dev/XCode Projects/...

Comment: So I'm still having the same error :-( I've moved the .db file into the same folder as where Xcode saved my project.  I've also copied it to the project inspector and used source control to add (it had a ? next to it).  The file is 20kb but the file in the debug area file path is 0kb so really confused why it's not finding the actual database.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible  that there's something wrong with the code to find and open the database?    Please see the code block in the original question.

Comment: I've solved this  a different way after googling loads of places and used the fileExists(atPath: String) way to open the database and all works as expected now.

Comment: Actually, turns out I haven't solved it!! It works in Simulator but crashes on my iPhone :-(  Can't open the database so I can only assume it hasn't been copied to the iPhone app.  This is proving really difficult!